# Titanium Alloy project fail to build

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

When attempting to build my app in Studio on Windows 7 the build fails with the following error:

> [ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process
>   exit value was 1

I got to command line and attempt to run then it fails with more information:

```
[DEBUG] :  Detecting modules in C:\ProgramData\Application Data\Titanium\modules
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:1011:11)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:802:34)
TRACE  | titanium exited with exit code 8
```

I don't know what is the reason for this. Any help?

Comment: Update your Titanium SDK, Alloy, Titanium CLI, Node, ... and try again. Does that help?

Comment: I tried to run it with many versions of android SDK (5.5.2, 5.5.1,4.4.2,4.0.0) but I got the same error. I tried to uninstall and reinstall titanium but fail to solve it.

Comment: Did you update the Titanium CLI? (I recently had an issue after updating the sdk, required a CLI update in addition). Running `titanium` on command line should give you something along the lines of `CLI version 4.0.0, Titanium SDK version 3.5.1.GA`

Comment: I did but noticed that it gives me N/V value for the CLI version. by the way I've an error in the tiapp.xml file at the line 84 : <target device="blackberry">false</target> Does this belong to this problem?